# Way to Install the MongoDB PHP Driver

Tags: php, mongodb, ubuntu-12.04

I'm trying to enable PHP for Mongo DB. Solution for that is same (install php5-dev first) in every forums but to installation fails with error.

Any idea how to solve issue?

Note: Using Ubuntu 12:04

```
jojo@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install php-pear php5-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php-pear : Depends: php5-cli but it is not going to be installed
 php5-dev : Depends: autoconf (>= 2.63) but it is not installable
            Depends: automake (>= 1.11) but it is not installable
            Depends: libtool (>= 2.2) but it is not installable
            Depends: shtool but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
jojo@ubuntu:~$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a fresh content for `sources.list` using [this page](http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/) and then installed Synaptic Package Manager to install new stuff which solved the problem..

Answer (score 9):

Assuming you have already installed MongoDB, You can install PHP driver for MongoDB by this command

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mongo
```

Comment: For people having problems with this, at least I did on 13.04, you probably need to enable the module first with `sudo php5enmod mongo`.

Comment: Also, the package only exists in Ubuntu 12.10+

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mongo
```

worked on PHP 5.5.9 / Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: I have PHP 5.5.16 on Ubuntu 12.04, installed Mongo through PECL and it didn't work, but it did with installing it this way.

Comment: @renicor Is PHP 5.5 the basic requirement for Mongo to run? Cant it function with PHP 5.3?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to do this:

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

And then install:

```
apt-get install php5-cli php5-dev
```

And then:

```
apt-get install php-pear
pecl install mongo
```

Comment: Got same error for `apt-get install php5-cli php5-dev`. Depends on this, depends on that....

Comment: Did you install packages from other repositories?

Comment: I use apt-get to install something and am not really expert in Linux.

Comment: I'll leave it to the Ubuntu people then!

Answer (score 0):

This seems less like an issue with installing `php5-dev`, or even the mongo extension, and more with the following conflicts:

```
Depends: autoconf (>= 2.63) but it is not installable
Depends: automake (>= 1.11) but it is not installable
Depends: libtool (>= 2.2) but it is not installable
Depends: shtool but it is not installable
```

You can get some more information on these with `sudo aptitude show <package>`, which may clue you in on other installed packages that they conflict with. From personal experience, I've only had to install the `build-essential` package to do any C/C++ compiling on Ubuntu. That high-level package usually ends up covering these dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/php/

This link gives all commands we need to execute for different operting system to  install php driver for mongoDb